# How can I add a Fragment into my Tabhost layout

Tags: android-fragments

I've downloaded the ActionBarSherlock and seen the styled sample code.In which there 2 RoundedColourFragments.I've seen the code and I was able to add and remove those fragments.But when I tried  to add it on my project I wasn't able.I think I can't find the correct layout where my fragment can be added.I'll provide you with the layout in case you can help me.Thank you for your time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/tabviewpager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```